# Negative numbers in binary (ones' complement and two’s complement)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I create 1's complement and 2's complement code for negative numbers in Python?

I had some problems with inversion and leading zero (one) in process.
I tried to use `res = bin(~int(bin(numb), 2))`, but it doesn't work.
I need result like:

```
Input: -123
Direct code: 11111011
Ones' complement code: 10000100
Two’s complement code: 10000101
```

Comment: Python doesn't use one's/two's complement natively, `bin(-123) == '-0b1111011'`. You will need to write the logic to generate other binary string representations yourself.

Comment: I need it just like exercise, not for working project, so I need a solution of making it in other way with sign bit in output.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `-` is two's complement and `~` is one's complement. The representation of both are negative numbers, because python integers has infinite digits. Positive means infinite `0`s, negative infinite `1`s. For display, you need to truncate the numbers to a finite amount of digits.

```
>>> '{:08b}'.format(-123 & 0xff)
'10000101'
>>> '{:08b}'.format(~123 & 0xff)
'10000100'
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to compute the 2's compliement:

```
def extra(x, bits = 64):
    mask = (1 << bits) - 1
    if x < 0:
        x = ((abs(x) ^ mask) + 1)
    return bin(x)[2:]
```

and like this for 1's complement:

```
def reverse(y, bits = 64):
    mask = (1 << bits) - 1
    if y < 0:
        y = (abs(y) ^ mask)
    return bin(y)[2:]
```